# Azure web app for containers- additional parameters for docker run command

Tags: docker, azure-appservice, azure-app-configuration, azure-web-app-for-containers, stackify

I have web application developed using the PHP and Laravel and trying to host in the Azure Web App for Containers service. I have integrated stackify logging functionality for the application and the server.

I need to send additional parameters to the docker run command in the azure web app for containers, need to pass the pid and v in the docker run command.

```
docker run -it --pid=host -v /usr/local/stackify:/usr/local/stackify
```

I did not find a way to configure. Please suggest a solution to resolve this. Is there any way configure the docker run commaned in the Azure web app for container service.

[image]

Comment: Where do you expect to get the volume from? With a command like this, it had to be on the machine your container is scheduled on.

Comment: I have followed this documentation https://docs.stackify.com/docs/php-apm-with-docker and it is working fine in the local environment while running the container with pid and host. Not sure how to add the params in azure web app for containers.